# Java - String array null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception, split

I get a null pointer exception. Why? I tried and debugged the code...Java says the String array is filled. But when i start the program without debugging mode, Java says nullpointerexception...

```
BufferedReader quelle = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String auftrag = quelle.readLine();
    String[] daten = auftrag.split(";");
//...
String test;

    for(int i = 3;i<=daten.length-1;i+=3)
    {

        test = daten[i-3] + " " + daten[i-2] + " " + daten[i-1];
        g.drawString(daten[i-3] + " " + daten[i-2] + " " + daten[i-1],x,y);
        y += 16;
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of your file?

Comment: Where do you get the NPE?

Comment: On which line of code do you get the NullPointerException ?

Comment: Where are you getting the Graphics object `g` from?

Comment: Nits: Do you mean to use `g.drawString(test, x, y)`? Also, `i<daten.length` is a bit easier than `i<=daten.length-1`.

Comment: I get the NullPointerException on the following line:

Comment: String[] daten = auftrag.split(";");

Comment: the content of my file is just a string,devided with semicolons in one line, the graphics g object is from the method head